# R: proper use of table()

Tags: r, matrix, statistics

Edit:

Because I'm still struggleing with this, here's additional information:

The matrix has the columns SessionID,UserID,query,[some time based parameters], length in words and length in chars

I want to get a frequency table of query and length, i.e. query, frequency of the query in matrix, length.

```
table(matrix$query,matrix$length)
```

yields a table without showing the actual queryname and a whole lot of columns

How do I use table() right to get the table I want?

Comment: Not so obvious (to me) that you have a memory problem.  Please post a small reproducible sample so we can see what sort of values your "query" data have.  The solution may be as simple as defining your `query` column as a factor and looking at the quantity per level, then creating `newmatrix <- oldmatrix[oldmatrix$query %in% X.frequent,]` (pseudocode) where `X.frequent` is a vector of the top X levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the `table` function: it is quite fast and will give the frequency of each query (you can alsos sort it), e.g.:

```
sort(table(mat[,"query"]))
```

Comment: use `tabulate()` if speed is of the utmost importance and the results contain no negative values